# Customize highcharts under the hood

Tags: highcharts

I'm working on a project with highcharts and got stuck customizing some detailed stuff inside the chart.

Here is the chart (with my needs):

[image: A Radar Graph generated by Highcharts]

I want to customize some of the labels (in the red circles), making them bold and bigger than the rest. I also want to change the style of those dots (in the green circles), making them bigger (or even replaced by a customized SVG graph) than the rest.

How do I achieve that? Is there any reference I need to read?

Thanks very much for any kind of tips!

---

Update, thanks for the great tips, I have made one step towards the target, but still have some questions, described in this picture:

[image: Further customization]

Comment: @RicardoLohmann I searched the docs but can't find related stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you can achieve this through highchart api. You can specify a marker for each data point. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.marker

Increasing the radius of the marker of first point:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Allocated Budget',
            data: [{
                name: 'Point 1',
                color: '#00FF00',
                y: 43000,
              marker: {
                    radius: 8
                }
            }, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }
```

And you can change the style of each xaxis label through label property of the xAxis. I found the answer from the following post. [Highchart - change color of one x-axis label only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182681/highchart-change-color-of-one-x-axis-label-only)

Changing the font-size of 'Marketing' point

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support', 
                    'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0,
        labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    if ('Marketing' === this.value) {
                        return '<span style="fill: red;">' + this.value + '</span>';
                    } else {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H8Ffq/28/)

You can modify the tooltip according to your needs (which pops on mouse hover on points). Just take a look at the example on highchart api:

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return 'The value for <b>'+ this.x +
                    '</b> is <b>'+ this.y +'</b>';
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-simple/

For changing the hover style of marker just take a look at marker object of data series. Here is an example of where the marker point doesn't change on hover too:

The example from highchart api (Same radius for each point):

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-states-hover-radius/

Keeping the size of marker radius on a single on point during a hover example:

```
data: [{
                name: 'Point 1',
                color: '#00FF00',
                y: 43000,
              marker: {
                    radius: 8,
                   states: {
                        hover: {
                            radius: 8
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000]
```

If I were you I would dig deep into highchart api, it is a great library which provides almost any kind of functinonality that you would need in modifying charts.

Comment: Thanks very much, I still have some questions for this. I have updated the question.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo I updated the answer, you can change the tooltip format in highcharts too. Highchart api provides almost all of the objects of the graph to modify it according to needs of developers .http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Comment: Thanks, I think the tooltip issue is quite clear now! But I don't think the example solves the hover-marker-size issue. It seems it's very hard to control that status. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I updated the answer @AwQiruiGuo which shows the example code snippet. Your question's answer can be found on the following page too: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.marker.states.hover